# Unity c# - Managing Character Sprites/Images in a VN Style Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

**Let me first explain the scenario of what I'm trying to do.**
I'm trying to create a VN like game where the characters change their image depending on the Time of the day. So for example, at daytime between 8:00AM to 11:00AM, The npc character named Benjamin would be standing by the pond in the scene and after 11:00AM he would sit by the campfire in the scene. This means that every npc character has many different sprites/images but only one of them should be activated depending on time of day.

I want to follow best practices when it comes to coding and structuring how my scripts work. So I don't want something that works but is done in a messy way and I feel like it could be improved. So this is how I did it:

```
public class Benjamin : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject BenjaminStanding;
    public GameObject BenjaminSitting;

    void Update()
    {
        //If Time logic Between 8:00AM - 11:00AM
        ActivateBenjaminStanding();

        //if Time logic is After 11:00AM
        ActivateBenjamindSitting();
    }

    //Activate Benjamin standing image
    public void ActivateBenjaminStanding()
    {      
        BenjaminSitting.SetActive(false);
        BenjaminStanding.SetActive(true);
    }

    //Activate Benjamin sitting image
    public void ActivateBenjamindSitting()
    {
        BenjaminStanding.SetActive(false);
        BenjaminSitting.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

In my hierarchy I have the empty gameobject Benjamin and then all the images under that parent object like this:

**Benjamin**

- BenjaminStanding
- BenjaminSitting

I attach the script to my Benjamin object and do all the necessary image referencing.

Now the above code works but I feel like this is very messy way of doing things, because if I have more characters I have to make individual scripts for each character, some may have few images, some might have lots. And I have to create a method for each image when activating them. So is there a better way of doing this?

I'm looking for something quicker, cleaner and efficient. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice. Thanks!

Comment: just as a general programming matter, you would surely use a Property (with an enum) for the character look

Comment: note that you almost certainly would NOT check every Update, heh!  Just have a signal that goes off, say, every ten minutes.  As a quick solution while you are developing, simply use `InvokeRepeating` say every ten seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a base class for your characters. Make it abstract class, and add variable and methods that all characters should have.

Like

```
public abstract class Character : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject characterStanding;
    public GameObject characterSitting;

    internal virtual void Update()
    {
        //If Time logic Between 8:00AM - 11:00AM
        ActivateCharacterStanding();

        //if Time logic is After 11:00AM
        ActivateCharacterSitting();
    }

    //Activate Benjamin standing image
    public void ActivateCharacterStanding()
    {      
        characterSitting.SetActive(false);
        characterStanding.SetActive(true);
    }

    //Activate Benjamin sitting image
    public void ActivateSitting()
    {
        characterStanding.SetActive(false);
        characterSitting.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Then you can create sub class and inherit from Character class.

```
    public class Benjamin : Character
{

}

    public class Marting: Character
{

    
}

    public class John: Character
{
   // You can change main class function and override it
   override Update(){
   // If you remove this doesn't apply base class function.
   base.ActivateCharacter();
```

}
}

But if every character have similar properties and you create many of them, this approach is not useful at all. You can use [Scriptable Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) you can create asset for every character and assign Scriptable Object to scene object or prefab, choose which way is good for your setup.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I been also thinking about making use of ScriptableObjects instead because all NPC's will have similar stats like money etc. But they won't have the same amount of images/sprites. Important npcs will have a lot more images and not so important ones will only have a couple at best.

Comment: You can create custom editor script and create enum for character types. Then according to selected type show field that you want to. Then create your character with inputs. That's not hard, maybe sound like a lot of work but trust me as your project goes bigger, you will appreciate it. Also, with a custom editor you will have more control over your character and asset design.

Comment: I have never created a custom editor yet but that does seem like a valuable thing to do from what I have seen. You get to basically play with settings and do things easily. I will have to both learn and experiment on that. Thanks

Comment: [CodeMonkey Custom Unity Editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMuTsAma4tk) or [Game Dev Guide Custom Editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_3DXBrH-Is&t=327s). I didn't watch personally but some of the videos of these youtubers were pretty good. You can start from these videos. [Unity Custom Editor Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease your labor by organizing your GameObjects into a data structure and using a single function for switching between images.

By doing so you can generalize your `Benjamin` class into a more general purpose class for any given character, giving your component re-usability.

This example uses a `Dictionary` to organize each GameObject by their name and assumes each image shares the same name as the GameObject,
so that the intended GameObject can be referenced by name. This way, instead of writing variables for each image and writing a method for each of them,
we can call a single function ( ex: `Activate("BenjaminStanding")` ).

```
public class ClassNameHere : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] images;

    private Dictionary<string, GameObject> imageDict;
    private GameObject currentImage;

    void Awake()
    {
        imageDict = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject image in images)
        {
            imageDict.Add(image.name, image);
        }
    }

    void Activate(string name)
    {
        if (currentImage) currentImage.SetActive(false);

        var image = imageDict[name];
        image.SetActive(true);

        currentImage = image;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //If Time logic Between 8:00AM - 11:00AM
        Activate("BenjaminStanding");

        //if Time logic is After 11:00AM
        Activate("BenjaminSitting");
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed, as I mention in my answer, for this type of thing a common solution is you put the time of day *in the name* of the file. (same for qualities like "sitting" "standing" laying" etc)  then you just parse that time or quality, and put *that* in the dictionary.

Comment: I really like the dictionary method, ill have to test yours and other's method out. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you have *many images* for each one, a common thing to do is just have an inspector variable that is an array,

```
 public ImageOrSomething[] avatars;
```

Note that then *in the Inspector* you can just put in as many images as you like, without any change in the code.

Note that where I say "ImageOrSomething" that could be anything ... a `Texture`, an `Image`, an entire animated character, some sprite sheet ... whatever it is in your situation.

Further...

You can actually just organize the images in your Resources folder and ***load them by name***.

In that way when your design department makes or changes images, or adds different times, you make no changes in the code.

Here's a kind of random example of loading a texture on to a card (think of playing cards say),

```
private int _Cardnumber = 1;
public int Cardnumber
{
    get { return _Cardnumber; }
    set
    {
        .. obviously check for valid numbers, etc

        string f = "bonuscards/bonus_" + Cardnumber.ToString();
        Texture t = Resources.Load(f, typeof(Texture)) as Texture;
        ri.texture = t;
    }
}
```

In the example the images would be named by your art department "bonus_3.png" "bonus_4.png" and so on.

You could additionally automatically determine what items are sitting in that folder and choose one randomly (or whatever the case may be).

## Regarding your 'time of day' example...

The smartass way to do it is just have the actual times ***in the image name.***

So something like

```
cat_03.png
cat_09.png
cat_13.png
```

would mean you change to those images at 0300, 0900 and 1300 respectively.

Say you want to add a new one for sleeping cat, and you want it to happen at 10pm.  ***All you do is add the new image,***

```
cat_22.png
```

just drop it in your resource folder and it is automatic from there.

Comment: some good advice thank you. Especially the naming style

Comment: yes, that's the "pro" way to do it if you will - exactly.  just write a few lines of code to parse the file names, and then it's all automatic from your art department.  indeed what you would do is simply load the files from a URL/whatever, and then your art department can *change how it all works* and test new images etc, without even doing anything at all in programming dept !